# Show if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5}{10^{3n}}$ converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to show if the serie

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5}{10^{3n}}$$

converges or diverges.

I'm very new to series (started studying today) and can't seem to find whether this serie converges or not. I know that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5}{10^{3n}}=5\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{10^{3n}}$$

and that the partial sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{10^{3n}}$ is

$$S_n=\frac{1}{10^3}+\frac{1}{10^6}+\frac{1}{10^9}+...+\frac{1}{10^{3n}}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{10^{3i}}$$

I have failed to find the limit of $S_n$, probably because I can't seem to simplify the sum into a single general formula. How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: check out [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: Multiply $\left(1-\frac{1}{10^3}\right)S_n=S_n-\frac{1}{10^3}S_n$ and cancel the resulting terms that have the same exponents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{5}{10^{3n}} = 5 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\dfrac{1}{1000}\bigg)^n $$

Do you see what kind of of series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\dfrac{1}{1000}\bigg)^n$ ? What i am trying to say is that not only you can show that the series converge, you can find the actual value of this convergent because it's a very well known series.

Comment: Oh of course! I wouldn't have seen that by myself. Thanks very much!